# Strange Process in Activity Monitor. Unable to search online

Tags: macos, activity-monitor

I (somewhat) recently did a fresh install, and the system was feeling a bit sluggish after installing Chrome and some extensions so I checked the Activity Monitor and found the below process. Anyone know what it is? I can't seem to search for it as none of the search engines I tried would take the special characters.

[image: weird process]

Comment: no idea, but if you click on the (i) icon above it will tell you who is causing it.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, that's a Safari Web Content process, although since you seem to be a Chrome user, it could also be Spotlight Web Content.